# Transformar URL XSLT

Tags: xml, sharepoint

Quiero transformar una url desde xslt con este formato:

```
[sitio]/PublishingImages/[nombreimagen].jpg
```

a este otro:

```
[sitio]/PublishingImages/_t/[nombreimagen]_jpg.jpg
```

Al principio intente usar replace, pero no se puede usar en la versión 1.0 asi que lo intente por otros medios intentando usar esta plantilla:

```
<xsl:template name=“string-replace“>
   <xsl:param name=“text“ />
   <xsl:param name=“pattern“ />
   <xsl:param name=“replace-with“ />
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=“contains($text, $pattern)“>
         <xsl:value-of select=“substring-before($text, $pattern)“ />
         <xsl:value-of select=“$replace-with“ />
         <xsl:call-template name=“string-replace“>
            <xsl:with-param name=“text“ select=“substring-after($text, $pattern)“ />
            <xsl:with-param name=“pattern“ select=“$pattern“ />
            <xsl:with-param name=“replace-with“ select=“$replace-with“ />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select=“$text“ />
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Llamando despues a la plantilla asi:

```
<xsl:variable name="primerreplace">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$ImageUrl" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="PublishingImages" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="PublishingImages/_t" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>                            
<xsl:variable name="segundoreplace">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$primerreplace" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select=".jpg" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="_jpg.jpg" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:value-of select="$segundoreplace">
```

Pero al cargar el Web-Part tengo el siguiente error:

```
XSLT compile error.
 at NPS.Styler.Webparts.Styler.b__0() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) at NPS.Styler.Webparts.Styler.get_XSLTDoc() at NPS.Styler.Webparts.Styler.GetHtmlXMLFormat()
```

Seguramente estoy haciendo algo mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que poner los argumentos string entre comillas y declarar el variable ImageUrl. (Gracias a [@Tim-C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585/tim-c).)

Suponiendo que el XML tiene la forma siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <URL>[sitio]/PublishingImages/[nombreimagen].jpg</URL>
</document>
```

Esto funcionaría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
            <xsl:param name="pattern" />
                <xsl:param name="replace-with" />
              <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $pattern)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $pattern)" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-with" />
                                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $pattern)" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="$pattern" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="$replace-with" />
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="URL">
        <xsl:variable name="ImageUrl" select="." />
    <xsl:variable name="primerreplace">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$ImageUrl" />
            <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'PublishingImages'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'PublishingImages/_t'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>                            
    <xsl:variable name="segundoreplace">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$primerreplace" />
            <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'.jpg'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'_jpg.jpg'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$segundoreplace" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```